# Как получить дочерний объект в который попал Raycast Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Возникла проблема, что луч всегда даёт информацию о родительском объекте.
Допустим объект состоит из двух пластин, луч попадает в первую, как мне получить, например её имя, а не имя родительского объекта?

```
Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, out hit, 100f);

hit.transform.gameObject.name //выдаёт имя родителя
//или
hit.collider.gameObject.name //тоже самое
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

луч попадет именно в тот обьект что держит две эти пластинки вместе, поэтому так происходит. У меня один вариант тут только остается
если на них висит риджидбади ,и скрепить их больше нечем только как объектом родителем,  то просто по скрипту в старте прописать
`GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;`
и по кд чекать попал ли на одну из них луч
и дальше делать уже то что тебе нужно, и если можно
опиши конкретнее что тебе нужно, кроме просто проверки
(как вариант можно на родительском объекте отключить коллайдер еще попробовать)

Comment: Думал про соединения, скорей всего так и придётся делать, хз как это на производительности будет, но kinematic = true - не вариант, у меня объект подвижный и движется физически. Спасибо больше.

Comment: Всё допёрло) `hit2.collider.transform.gameObject.name`

Comment: ну сори, не юзаю просто лучи, это для меня лес и мрак, я уже пробовал пару раз, слишком муторно для меня

Answer (score 0):

`hit.collider.transform.gameObject.name`

Просто краткий ответ

Comment: Хочу дополнить.
`hit.collider.transform.gameObject.name` - хранит одновременно все имена объектов, через которые прошёл луч, даже дочерних, ток спустя 4 часа это понял.